# Pass object-props to the constructor of a new object

Tags: javascript, json

I got an object like this, which comes from http-api:

```
- id
- name
- value
- type
- parent
- children
```

Now I would like to use those values to create a new object. At the moment I am doing this:

```
export default class MyObject {

    constructor (id, name, value, type, parent = null, children = []) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = children;
    }

    // provide fancy methods
}
```

```
new MyObject(attr.id, attr.name, attr.value, attr.type, attr.parent, attr.children);
```

This works fine, but the larger the object is, the larger the params and I may be lost in having the right ordering.

As I consume an HTTP-api the ordering of the original API-response may change. So I can not assume that `id` will always be the first prop of this object.

Is there an elegant way to create objects from this kind of API-response?

Comment: why not use `attr` directly? are you using typescript?

Comment: I would like to add methods that are available in `MyObject`, which is used in multiple views in my app.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51990967/4051471) help?

Comment: If you have too many arguments, use an options object instead. You should be able to directly pass the `attr` value then.

Comment: "*I got an object like this*" - what exactly are you getting there? That doesn't look like an object to me. How does this relate to the `attr` in your code?